# How to retrieve currently applied node configuration from Riak v2.0+

Tags: riak

**Showing currently applied configuration values**

In v2.0+ of Riak there is a new command option: `riak config effective`

Which I [read](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/configs/configuration-files/#Retrieving-a-Configuration-Listing) as it would tell you the current running values of riak.

> At any time, you can get a snapshot of currently applied
>   configurations through the command line. For a listing of all of the
>   configs currently applied in the node

---

**Config changes applied only on start of each node?**

In multiple locations in Riak [documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/backends/multi/#Configuring-Multiple-Backends) there is reference like:

> Remember that you must stop and then re-start each node when you
>   change storage backends or modify any other configuration

---

**Problem:**

However when I made a change to a setting (I've tested this in both riak.conf and advanced.conf), I see the newest value when running: `riak config effective`

ie:

1. Start node: `riak start`
2. View current setting for log level: `riak config effective | grep log.console.level`

> log.console.level = info

3. Change the level to debug (something that will output a lot to console.log)
4. Re-run: `riak config effective | grep log.console.level`, we get:

> log.console.level = debug

5. Checking the console log file for debug: `cat /var/log/riak/console.log | grep debug`  give no results (indicating the config change has not been applied)

So the question is, how can I retrieve and verify what config setting each Riak node is running under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Riak starts, it creates two files: 'app..config' and 'vm..config'.  The default location is in a 'generated.configs' directory under the platform data directory (usually /var/lib/riak).

These files will contain the settings that were in place when Riak was started.  The command `riak config effective` processes the current riak.conf and advanced.config files.

Comment: So, the documentation in Riak is misleading by saying it will give `a listing of all of the configs **currently applied** in the node`? it should say instead **to be applied on next start**